# Arcgis Service Find the Closest Road Segment By giving an GPS Point

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server

Within ArcMap, I have a road sement layer. I can add a point feature, and get the closest road segment by using near_analysis tool.
[image]

**I want to do it through an ArcGIS service. Based on a given point(lan, lon), I can get the closest road segment through an Restful API.**

I publish my model, my road segment and the static point feature to my local ArcGIS server. Also, I can get the closest road segment id through an Restful API, but I cannot change the point feature dynamically.
[image]

Comment: I think what is happening is your taxi layer is being published a static feature layer. So every time the geoprocessing service is called it is using the same point. Try turning the taxi feature layer into a model parameter. Then when you call the service you can pass it a new point feature layer.

Comment: how to turn the point feature into model parameters like x and y coordinates? @Dowlers

Comment: right click on the Taxi input and select Model Parameter.